# Set maps given by a polynomial & Yoneda Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

This Exercise 4.1. from the book Algebraic Geometry I, by Gortz.

**Problem** Let $R$ be a ring, and for every $R$-algebra $A$ let $\alpha_A:A\rightarrow A$ be a map of sets such that for every $R$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi: A\rightarrow A'$, one has $\varphi\circ\alpha_A=\alpha_{A'}\circ\varphi$. Prove that there exists a polynomial $P\in R[x]$ such that for every $A$ and every $a\in A$, $\alpha_A(a)=P(a)$ in two different ways: (i) Not using Yoneda Lemma and (ii) Using Yoneda Lemma.

Attempt at a solution:

This is not using Yoneda Lemma:

Let $A$ be any $R$-algebra, $\alpha_A:A\rightarrow A$ any set map. Let $\alpha_{A'}:A'\rightarrow A'$, where $A'=R[x]$ be a set map, given by $x\mapsto P(x)$.

My claim is that $\alpha_{A'}(x)$ is the desired polynomial. To see this, let $a\in A$ be any such element. Let, $\varphi: R[x]\to A$ by $x\mapsto a$, be an $R$-algebra homomorphism. Then, by hypothesis we have: $\varphi\circ \alpha_{A'}=\alpha_A\circ\varphi.$

So, $$\alpha_A(a)=\alpha_A(\varphi(x))=\varphi(\alpha_{A'}(x))=\alpha_{A'}(\varphi(x))=\alpha_{A'}(a)=P(a).$$

This seems really silly to me, and almost with no content. Did I make a silly mistake somewhere, or maybe I misinterpreted the problem completely?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You mean the book by Wedhorn & Görtz?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Yes, that is the book. I should have written the whole name of the book and authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice when you don't want to use the Yoneda Lemma, you actually repeat the proof of the Yoneda Lemma in a special case. Your proof is correct. And it *has* a content, namely that $x \in R[x]$ is the universal element of an $R$-algebra. Every element of an $R$-algebra "comes" from this $x$.

Comment: This helps put things in perspective. Thanks!